# how to invoke the neweset one week recored in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

how to write the code in php that invoke the neweset one week articles' title in mysql? eg: the table name is "threads". the time field is "dateline" whose style is like this (1300774889), the article title is "subject". thank you.i want to invoke 10 records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like :

```
Select * from THREADS where dateline > date_sub(now(), interval 1 week) order by dateline desc;
```

you can format your date in PHP with date() function, or directly in mysql using FROM_UNIXTIME

Comment: i wanto invoke 10 record. i add limit 0 9 to the code. am i right.

Comment: Nope. You add `LIMIT 10` or `LIMIT 0,10` to only return the first 10 results.